# ModuleNotFoundError: my script can't find the module that I had written for my data analysis

Tags: python, package, anaconda, data-analysis, modulenotfounderror

I am working on project for my thesis and wrote a data analysis program with fellow students. Originally I had used the program on my windows laptop where everything worked just fine. Unfortunately, my laptop broke and now I have to use a Macbook. Theoretically, the switch should not be a problem; however, when I attempt to run the same program with the same file structures as on the windows laptops, the program cannot find the module. I will place the code, hierarchical structure of the files, and the error below. Thanks for your help. This one has been really annoying :(

```
# Add the path of the PyOTIC Software to the system path
# Adjust this path to where the PyOTIC Software package is located
#import sys
#sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\FX\\Desktop\\Uni\\python\\MA\\SF\\stepfinder')
#print(sys.path)

#Load investigator package
import pyoti
pyoti.info()


#Create an experiment and open a new temporary experiment dbfile
# experiment = pyoti.open_experiment()
experiment = pyoti.open_experiment(filename=datadir+'/'+datafile.replace('.bin','.fs'))


# Import necessary modules and functions 
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('module://ipympl.backend_nbagg')
import numpy as np
#import os
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker
import setuptools

# Import stepfinder software
import sys

#sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\fiona\\Thesis\\Python\\packages\\stepfinder') this was the old filepath in windows 
sys.path.append('~Users/bfielden/Documents/practice/packages/stepfinder') #new file path in mac
import stepfinder as sf

from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.container { width:90% !important; }</style>"))
#from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from pylab import rcParams


# Import plotting style for Cellular Nanoscience
sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\fiona\\Thesis\\Python\\packages\\cnplotstyle')
import cn_plot_style as cnps
print(sys.path)
```

and here is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/hk/hcjxgg5j3cqc92fd31wwp1640000gn/T/ipykernel_8584/3585989268.py in <module>
     29 #sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\fiona\\Thesis\\Python\\packages\\stepfinder')
     30 sys.path.append('~Users/bfielden/Documents/practice/packages/stepfinder')
---> 31 import stepfinder as sf
     32 
     33 from IPython.core.display import display, HTML

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stepfinder'
```

and the file structure for the project:

```
    practice/
--------data/
------------B4/
--------------(300)B4_stepfinder.ipynb (main script)
--------packages/
----------------stepfinder/
--------------------------_init_.py
--------------------------stepfinder.py
--------------------------stepfinder.ipynb
----------------cnplotstyle/
--------------------------_init_.py
--------------------------cnplotstyle.py
----------------ASWAD/
---------------------ASWAD.cfg
```

I tried different ways of finding the path without avail. I thought maybe, the Mac system would not recognise the backslashes for windows, so I changed them to the forward slashes, but that didn't work either. I tried rearranging the file structure, but that didn't work either. The same error keeps occurring. (Also, it should be noted that Im doing this all in anaconda.) Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Which `.py` file are you showing us here? Also, how do you run the code? I.e.: what is the current working directory, and what command do you type?

Comment: the program running is the (300)B4_stepfinder.ipynb. So I don't type in a command, I just run the script in anaconda. The working path up until the point where I call upon the stepfinder module is as follows: '/Users/bfielden/Documents/practice/data/B4'

Comment: Rather than `'~Users/bfielden/Documents/practice/packages/stepfinder'`, have you tried an absolute path without the `~` shortcut?

Comment: yes I tried an absolute path as well and the same error occurred